# iOS Basics Guide Xcode not responding properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am following the iOS basics guide from apple. I am currently on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1
and when it asks to add the constraints to the textbox I do, just like it says. I run it, turn sideways, nothing happens. I clear the constraints and try again - nothing happens. I update the frames - still nothing.

I figured I'd continue on through the tutorial. I get to the next 'checkpoint' and try to run the program with the new table view controller as the default or initial view controller - surprise, nothing changes. I have no idea how one even begins to debug this issue. I've closed out of everything Xcode related, tried again, and nothing changes.

Comment: Are you using the simulator or a phone? Have you checked if the rotation lock is on?

Comment: I am using the simulator. How would I check if the rotation lock is on in the simulator? Plus, this doesn't address the issue of initial table view

Comment: It's unlikely that it's on but if you open the simulator and go to the home screen you can access the control centre by swiping from the bottom like you would on an iPhone.

Comment: It's not that I cannot rotate. I can rotate just fine. It's that the constraints do not respond properly on rotate.

Comment: I've just followed the tutorial and I get the textfield stretching across the view like in the tutorial picture so I'm not sure why the constraints aren't working for you.

Comment: Yea. It's odd. And it isn't just that. It is the next step as well.

Comment: It is very strange. I added the tableViewController, clicked the Initial View Controller check box, ran the program and I see the tableview immediately. Are you getting any errors out into the console?

Comment: No, no errors. I suppose I could scrap it and start again. Though, I have a hard time understanding why anything would change. It acts like a setting is not correct, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped the project and created a new one. It all works fine now. I still have no idea why, though.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so others won't read through all the comments for nothing.

Comment: I will when I can, in 2 days -__-